# Google Analytics Drupal browser

Tags: 7, google-analytics

"Drupal" is showing in our Google Analytics as the top browser. We're using Drupal 7 with the google_analytics module. What could cause this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you use many modal frames or many functions like `$result = drupal_http_request($url, $options);` on your site?

In both these cases the user agent is set to "Drupal".